# Machine learning - Check document is valid or invalid using algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new in machine learning. I have a requirement to predict if document is valid or invalid. Here I have only 10000 valid documents(No any invalid documents). I saw some algorithm for ex: Naive Byes, SVM etc.. Here the concept is to train model we have to provide both type documents(Valid and Invalid) then it can only predict document by comparing with both trained document.

Is there any process or algorithm, Using this we can say document is valid or invalid(May be showing in percentage for ex: 40% valid and 60% invalid) by using only valid documents?

Comment: you should ask the question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way could be to go for a **one class classification**. In machine learning, one-class classification (OCC) attempts
to identify objects of a specific class by learning from
a training set containing only the objects of that class. The
task in OCC is to define a classification boundary around the
positive (target) class, such that it accepts as many objects as
possible from the positive class, while minimizing the chance
of accepting negative (outlier) objects. It is a one-versus-rest
classification, where the rest are not observed during training. In your case the model will learn to classify and indentify valid document, the rest are invalid documents.